# How can users add to a database in Django

Tags: python, django, database

Within the admin app it's possible to add to a database. But is there a way where users who have accounts on the website can add to the database. For example a playlist where a user can add information about songs to

Comment: yes, there is a way and these things are called forms/modelforms. You need to read about them.

Comment: https://djangobook.com/the-django-book/ go through this tutorial, it will help